# JavaFX: FileChooser is blinking

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

It first appears in the left upper corner of the screen and then shows in the middle of the screen.

It is code:

```
 private static File fileChooserDialog(  final String initialDirectory, final String initialFileName, final boolean open,
                                        final String filterString, final String... extensions) {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(filterString, extensions);
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    File resultFile;

    if(open) {
        resultFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    } else {
        resultFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
    }

    if(resultFile != null) {
        lastSelectedFilePath = resultFile.getParent();
    }

    return resultFile;
}
```

Comment: `lastSelectedFilePath` is not defined

Comment: Thanks everyone for answerr, I had used RootPaneUI.getParent() instead stage and it helped me;

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new `Stage` every time you want to show a `FileChooser`. ***Remove this line:***

```java
Stage stage = new Stage();
```

And use your application's `Window` as an owner for the `FileChooser`. For example, if you are trying to show this dialog when the user clicks a button, you can get the `Window` like this:

```java
Button button = new Button("Browse");
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    Window window = button.getScene().getWindow();
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(window);
    event.consume();
});
```